# nuxt.jsのfirebaseモジュールでfirebase.firestore.FieldPathがundefinedになってしまう。

Tags: javascript, firebase, nuxt.js

nuxt.jsでfirebaseモジュールを使用しているのですが、
store内で対象テーブルのIDに`artistIds`のIDを持っているデータを抽出したく、下記コードを作成しましたが、`this.$fire.firestore.FieldPath`が`undefined`になってしまい動作しません。

```
const arQs = await this.$fire.firestore
  .collection('artists')
  .where(this.$fire.firestore.FieldPath.ducumentId(), 'in', artistIds)
  .get()
```

`this.$fire.firestore`は`undefined`ではないので取得できるかと考えていたのですが、他に代替手段等ございましたらご教授いただければと思います。

該当するドキュメント
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/firestore/field-path?hl=ja

参照したリンク
https://qiita.com/xerroxcopy/items/c08bf7068c4b602b02d1

Answer (score 0):

`this.$fireModule.firestore.FieldPath.documentId()`で取得できました。